# Inline table editing with select2 not working

Tags: php, laravel, jquery-select2, laravel-livewire

Hi can somebody please guide me how to implement inline table edit with select2 in laravel livewire?

I am having problem in my select as I can change the selected option in my select2 but the value I am getting upon submitting the form is the same as the original value.

Please see code below.

Table

```
@foreach ($purchaserequestitems as $index => $purchaserequestitem)
    <tr >
        <td><label class='label label-primary'>{{ $loop->iteration }}</label></td>
        <td>
            @if($editedPRItemsIndex !== $index)
                <label>
                    {{ $purchaserequestitem['item']['name'] }}
                </label>
                <br/>
                <small>
                    <label>{{ $purchaserequestitem['item']['code'] }}</label>
                </small>
            @else
                <select wire:model.defer="purchaserequestitems.{{ $index }}.item_id" data-index="{{ $index }}" wire:change="getUomByItemId" class="form-control select2 item">
                    <option value="">-- Please Select -- </option>
                    @foreach ($items as $item)
                        <option value="{{ $item->id }}" >{{ $item->name }}</option>
                    @endforeach   
                </select>
            @endif
        </td>
        <td>
            @if ($editedPRItemsIndex !== $index)
                {{ $purchaserequestitem['quantity'] }}
            @else
                <input type="text" wire:model.defer="purchaserequestitems.{{ $index }}.quantity" class="form-control">
            @endif
        </td>
        <td>
            @if ($editedPRItemsIndex !== $index)
                {{ $purchaserequestitem['itemuomconversion']['unitmeasure']['code'] }}
            @else
                <select wire:model.defer="purchaserequestitems.{{ $index }}.item_uom_conversion_id" id="edituom" class="form-control select2">
                    <option value="">-- Please Select -- </option>
                    @foreach ($uom_options as $uom_option)
                        <option value="{{ $uom_option->id }}">{{ $uom_option->unitmeasure->code }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            @endif
            
        </td>
        <td>
            @if ($editedPRItemsIndex !== $index)
                {{ $purchaserequestitem['comment'] }}
            @else
                <textarea wire:model.defer="purchaserequestitems.{{ $index }}.comment" class="form-control"></textarea>
            @endif
        </td>
        <td>
        <span class='pull-right'>
            @if ($editedPRItemsIndex !== $index)
                <button 
                    class='btn btn-primary btn-sm rounded-0 py-0'
                    wire:click.prevent="editPRItem({{ $index }})">
                    Edit
                </button>
                <button 
                    wire:click="deleteConfirm({{ $purchaserequestitem['id'] }})" 
                    class='btn btn-danger btn-sm rounded-0 py-0'> 
                    Delete
                </button>
            @else
                <button wire:click.prevent="update({{ $index }})" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
            @endif
        </span>
    </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

JS that sets the value of the select

```
$('.item').on('change', function (e) {
    let data = $(this).val();
    let idx = $(this).data('index');
    @this.set(`purchaserequestitems.${idx}.item_id`, data);
});
```

Function that updates the data

```
public function update($prItemIndex)
{
    $pritem = $this->purchaserequestitems[$prItemIndex] ?? NULL;
    if(!is_null($pritem)){
        $editedItem = PurchaseRequestItem::find($pritem['id']);
        if($editedItem){
            // dd($pritem);
            $editedItem->update([
                'item_id' => $pritem['item_id'],
                'comment' => $pritem['comment'],
                'quantity' => $pritem['quantity'],
                'item_uom_conversion_id' => $pritem['item_uom_conversion_id']
            ]);
        }
    }
    $this->editedPRItemsIndex = null;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, or if you guys have any other way to implement an inline table editing with a select2 in it. Thank you

Tried to put the js inside an eventlistener but everytime I change the an option on the select box, it will just return to its original value.

Comment: You have this in a loop, so you are violating the basic rule that IDs must be unique; that is the first thing you will need to fix.

Comment: Yeah forgot to mention that I already tried it with a class as a selector, but not working also.